# MomentJS changing value when assigned to new variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs

When I try assigning a moment to a new variable it changes the value without me modifying it.

I have tried everything from forcing the use of UTC and settings timezones. It just keeps changing the value.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-appointment-create',
  templateUrl: './appointment-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./appointment-create.component.css']
})
export class AppointmentCreateComponent implements OnInit {

  appointment: CreateAppointmentDto;
  form: FormGroup;
  private formSubmitted: boolean;
  tasks: Task[];
  availability: Availability[];
  task: number;
  availablemoments: Moment[];

  constructor(
    private titleService: Title,
    private router: Router,
    private appointmentService: AppointmentService,
    private taskService: TasksService,
    private webLogger: WebloggerService,
    private availabilityService: AvailabilityService,
  ) {
    this.appointment = new CreateAppointmentDto();
  }

  dateFilter = (d: Moment): boolean => {
    return this.availability.filter(s => s.timestampstart.isSame(d, 'day')).length >= 1;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.titleService.setTitle('New Appointment');

    this.taskService.getActiveTasks().subscribe(value => {this.tasks = value; });

    this.form = new FormGroup({
      timestampstart: new FormControl(this.appointment.timestampstart, Validators.required),
      daystart: new FormControl(this.appointment.timestampstart, Validators.required),
      location: new FormControl(this.appointment.location, Validators.required),
      description: new FormControl(this.appointment.description, Validators.required),
      paid: new FormControl(false, Validators.required),
      serviceType: new FormControl(this.appointment.serviceTypeId, Validators.required),
      client: new FormControl(this.appointment.clientId, Validators.required),
      assignedUser: new FormControl(this.appointment.assignedUserId, Validators.required),
    });
  }

  onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.formSubmitted = true;

    if (this.form.valid) {
      this.form.disable();
      this.appointment.timestampstart = this.form.get('timestampstart').value;
      this.appointment.location = this.form.get('location').value;
      this.appointment.description = this.form.get('description').value;
      this.appointment.paid = this.form.get('paid').value;
      this.appointment.serviceTypeId = this.form.get('serviceType').value;
      this.appointment.clientId = this.form.get('client').value;
      this.appointment.assignedUserId = this.form.get('assignedUser').value;
      this.appointmentService.createNewAppointment(this.appointment)
        .subscribe(value => { this.router.navigate([`/dashboard/appointment/${value.id}/edit`]); });
    } else {
      this.webLogger.error('The form is invalid, please check the values');
    }
  }

  selectTask($event: Event) {
    this.task = Number(this.form.get('serviceType').value);
    this.availabilityService.getAvailabilityForTask(this.task).subscribe(value => {
      this.availability = value;
    });
  }

  setTime($event: Event) {
    this.availablemoments = [];
    const dayAvailability: Availability[] = this.availability.filter(
      s => s.timestampstart.isSame(moment(this.form.get('daystart').value), 'day'));
    const currentDate = dayAvailability.reduce((prev, curr) => prev.timestampstart < curr.timestampstart ? prev : curr).timestampstart;
    dayAvailability.forEach(value => {
      while (value.timestampend.isAfter(currentDate)) {
        if (!this.availablemoments.includes(moment(currentDate))) {
          this.availablemoments.push(moment(currentDate));
        }
        currentDate.add(30, 'minutes');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

this.availability is a list of Availability objects which include start and end moments

I expect the second console log to return the same as the first console log.

UPDATE:

The Availability class looks like this:

```
export class Availability {
  id: number;
  timestampstart: Moment;
  timestampend: Moment;
  location: string;
  description: string;
  paid: boolean;
  payment: Invoice;
  serviceType: Task;
  client: Client;
  assignedUser: User;

  static serialize(data: any): Availability {
    const user: Availability = Object.assign(new this(), data);
    if (data.hasOwnProperty('timestampstart')) {
      user.timestampstart = moment(data.timestampstart);
    }
    if (data.hasOwnProperty('timestampend')) {
      user.timestampend = moment(data.timestampend);
    }
    if (data.hasOwnProperty('serviceType')) {
      user.serviceType = Task.serialize(data.serviceType);
    }
    if (data.hasOwnProperty('client')) {
      user.client = Client.serialize(data.client);
    }
    if (data.hasOwnProperty('assignedUser')) {
      user.assignedUser = User.serialize(data.assignedUser);
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

Comment: what values are in the array to begin with? What value does the first log command produce? What value does the second command produce? It's much easier to comprehend the problem if you give us some data to work with.

Comment: This is probably not an issue with Moment. More than likely the value is being changed inside the `Availability` class. Can we see that?

Comment: I've updated the post to show the Availability class. The serialize function is used to properly initiate some of the values including the moments.

Comment: Can we also have some sample data, expected output, and actual output as well please, as previously requested. Also this looks like TypeScript code, am I correct? I added a tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, since I was using Angular, I assigned the formControlName to the wrong HTML tag (the option tag instead of the select) causing the get of the value to return a value that I wasn't expecting. I've updated the main post to show the entire code.